# How to save oracle apex applications files to Object Storage through ATP?

Tags: oracle-apex, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need to save my oracle applications files to object storage in oracle cloud infrastructure through ATP. I am able to do the reverse, but not getting a solution for my problem.

I tried this:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_CREDENTIAL(
    credential_name => 'DEF_CREDS',
    username => 'cloud@oracle.com',
   password => 'password'
   );
   END;

BEGIN
DBMS_CLOUD.PUT_OBJECT(
credential_name => 'DEF_CREDS',
object_uri => '',
directory_name => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
file_name => 'tstschema.dmp');
END;
```

But this copies file from object store to ATP.

want to store apex applications files to object storage through ATP. Please help me, I'm stuck in this from a very long time.

Comment: Your credentials name is different. If this is a direct copy-paste then, that may be the root-cause. Also, I am assuming that you intentionally removed the object_uri value for security reasons when posting on SO. Next, make sure that the bucket and objects permissions are set up correctly for your object storage.